# Meteor Blaze To-Do App Error, can't find npm module "meteor/Mongo"

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Everything worked perfectly well until I made the changes that were stated while learning Collections. I also had a few updates done for Meteor through the command prompt. I don't seem to know where the problem resides.

The error says - can't find npm module "meteor/Mongo"

[image: The Error Message]

Comment: PS: I'm learning from the To-Do App tutorial that is given on Meteor's homepage. :)

Comment: Please paste the error text into your question. Questions here should be reproducible. That means you need to include some more details about what you've done as well.

Comment: First day here. Sorry, I'm just getting the hang of things here. :)

Comment: No problem! It's a challenge at the start but worthwhile to learn how to use the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've capitalised `meteor/Mongo` in the path in your `import` statement - it should be `import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo"`